# Exception Handling when using both web and token api gaurd

Tags: laravel

Using laravel5.8.  Using both web and API(Token Gaurd).
when using api call with invalid api_token parameter receiving an error Route:Login not defined.  I want the response in JSON.  Read in Forum I need to use the below way in app\Exceptions\Handler.php and it works.   I have web gaurd for some of the paths.   I want the route:login to work when its a web gaurd and return json response when using api gaurd. How can I do it in Laravel 5.8?

```
  public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
      //  dd(get_class($exception));
       // return parent::render($request, $exception);
        return response()->json(
            [
                'errors' => [
                    'status' => 401,
                    'message' => 'Unauthenticated',
                ]
            ], 401
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I put the logic in `unauthenticated` function, combines with `expectsJson()` should solve your problem

```
// in app\Exceptions\Handler.php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}

protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['status' => 401,'message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest('/');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.   When I call the api with invalid api_token parameter its not calling unauthenticated method.

Comment: your API authentication method (with api_token) is new in Laravel 5.8. My answer is for Laravel API Authentication using Laravel Passport (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport)